# Android download manager not downloading files from https

Tags: android, ssl, android-download-manager

In my Android app I download media files from Amazon service CloudFront.

Sample link: https://testcdn.grouvi.org/uploads/94498583-94c4-44b8-911e-2e0c6bcc4b27/86e55069-2627-4c96-9cbe-98fc87f2eb1b.jpg

This is my code:

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

and on some phones with Android Kitkat I get this error

```
W/DownloadManager﹕ Aborting request for download 840: while trying to execute request: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x752a9a60: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x7362ad74:0x00000000)
```

Is there any way I can overcome SSL handshake failure in Android DownloadManager?

Comment: We solved this issue by handling downloads by ourselves via background thread.